# Testing the Anderson–Darling and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem, anderson-darling-test

I was trying to simulate the Central Limit Theorem in R. Unfortunately, even in large samples (e.g., 80), the Anderson–Darling test could not recognize normality. Therefore, I wrote the following code to see when the p-values become large enough so that the null hypothesis is not rejected.

The results were quite peculiar...

Firstly, it seems that the ability to reject the null hypothesis is rare.
[image]
Secondly, there appears to be periodicity in the p-values that are not significant. This periodicity persists even when I remove or modify `set.seed(i+n_s*j)`.
[image]

Why does this happen?

This is my code:

```
library(nortest)
# Number of experiments for recording p-values
n_e <- 70
# Creating a list for the p-values
a_d <- rep(0, n_e)
# Number of samples to be examined
n_s <- 1000
# Size of each sample
s_s <- 30:(30+n_e-1)
for (j in 1:n_e){
  # Creating a list for sample means
  s_m <- rep(0, n_s)
  for (i in 1:n_s) {
    # Specifying the sample distribution
    set.seed(i+n_s*j)
    r_n <- rexp(s_s[1], 8)
    # Sample mean
    m <- mean(r_n)
    # Populating the list with sample means
    s_m[i] <- m
  }
  # Populating the list with p-values
  a_d[j] <- ad.test(s_m)$p.value
}
plot(s_s, a_d)
boxplot(a_d)
```

Comment: The CLT does not say anything about finite sample sizes. Don't expect the distribution of standardized means to be *exactly* normally distributed at any finite sample size (an exception is if the parent population is normal). In that light, using a formal normality hypothesis test seems futile. Importantly: Failure to reject normality does not mean that the sample is normally distributed.

Comment: @COOLSerdash , However, in practice, we only have finite samples. Moreover, as far as I know, the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) is not limited to samples from a normally distributed population but holds more generally. The issue is that these requirements for the CLT practically invalidate the use of the z-test and confidence intervals for the population mean.

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating the experiment each tie with sample size s_s[1] which equals 30. This is insufficient to make the CLT kick in. If you increase it, you will see that the p-value distribution becomes uniform.

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that. Unfortunately, the problem persists even if I change s_s[1] to s_s[j].

Comment: Because in the lower ranges of s_s, the sample size is too low for CLT, yielding non-normally distributed means.

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem (CLT) can, I believe, be applied even to samples with a size of 30. In any case, I (if I'm not mistaken) start with samples of size `s_s[1]=30` and end up with samples of size `s_s[n_e]=30+n_e-1`, which means a size of 100. Are these still considered small? Moreover, I don't see any differentiation in the p-values as I increase the sample sizes.

Comment: 30 is just a rule of thumb for data that are already close to normality anyway. Speed of convergence (i.e. the sample size needed to see normality) depends on many factors, e.g. on skewness of the data. Since you draw data from an exponential distribution, larger sample sizes may be needed.

Comment: @Kώστας If you believe that "n=30" is sufficient, try lognormal with $\sigma=4$  -- e.g. try `x=replicate(10000,mean(rlnorm(1000,-5,4)))`. That's means of sample size 1000. Try: `hist(x)` and `hist(log(x))`. Notice that the log of the means is still somewhat right skew, even though the things being averaged must be symmetric on the log-scale. .... this is a distribution for which the actual CLT holds (which theorem says nothing whatever about n=30, or any other finite sample size). Then try replacing the sample size of 1000 with a sample size of 100000 (you'll want to drop the number of sims).

Comment: Even averages of one million observations doesn't get close to symmetry! See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTMu0.png

Comment: @Knarpie I performed these tests for samples up to 630. The same issue persists. Moreover, one would expect that the p-values would increase as the sample size grows, but again, this is not happening.

Comment: @Glen_b What concerns me is that the effectiveness of the z-test and confidence intervals relies on the universality of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT). That is, since the sample means of ANY distribution follow a normal distribution, I can make an estimation of the population mean, regardless of its distribution.

Comment: 1. Testing is pointless; unless the original population distribution was already normal, *the null is always false at any finite sample size*. Why test null hypotheses guaranteed to be false? The reason why p-values don't seem to "settle" down is goodness of fit test's ability to pick up deviation from non-normality improves with sample size.  2. "effectiveness of the z-test and confidence intervals" Testing normality doesn't measure "effectiveness";' what matters for a test is accuracy of significance level and maintaining power. What matters for a CI is maintaining coverage and average width

Comment: 3. "That is, since the sample means of ANY distribution follow a normal distribution" This assertion is simply false... and it's not what the CLT says.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my mistake. Instead of creating a population that is exponentially distributed and then drawing samples and calculating their means, I was continuously generating exponentially distributed populations and calculating their means. After the correction (see below), it seems to work even for sample sizes ranging from 30 to 80 (see the image).

[image]

```
library(nortest)
# We will start with samples of size d1 and end up with size d2
d1 <- 30
d2 <- 80
# Size of each sample
m_d <- d1:d2
# In each iteration, for each sample size,
# we will examine p_d samples of this size,
# recording their p-values
p_d <- 1000
# The list of p-values will consist of d2-d1+1 p-values,
# one for each sample size case
a_d <- rep(0, d2-d1+1)
# Population
pl <- runif(10000, min=0, max=1)
#pl <- rexp(10000, 8)
# Index for a_d
k <- 1
# Index for set.seed
s_s <- 1
for (j in m_d){
  # Creating the list with sample means
  d_m <- rep(0, p_d)
  for (i in 1:p_d) {
    # Determining the sample distribution
    set.seed(10*s_s)
    r_n <- sample(pl, size = j)
    # Sample mean
    m <- mean(r_n)
    # Enriching the list with sample means
    d_m[i] <- m
    s_s <- s_s+1
  }
  # Normalizing the list of sample means
  #d_m <- (d_m-mean(d_m))/sd(d_m)
  # Enriching the list with p-values
  a_d[k] <- ad.test(d_m)$p.value
  k <- k+1
}
plot(m_d, a_d)
abline(h = 0.05)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of the simulation are not well calibrated. The CLT is an asymptotic result so, for a finite sample of *any* size, the actual sampling distribution of the mean is close to but not exactly normal. So, you can choose enough experimental replications to make a normality test arbitrarily powerful - that is to say, I'd reject the hypothesis that the distribution of the sample mean is normal with a given probability encroaching 1. Even if the sample size is 10,000 and the "CLT kicks in" as one answer states, I can change the number of experimental replications to 1,000,000 or more to get that test to reject normality almost every time.

The AD test is not giving you false positives here, the data are not normal. You can understand this simulation a little bit better if you caveat the results by saying the $p$ value from the AD test is used as a pragmatic measure of similarity to the normal distribution.